# CSS Only Menu System

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I have a simple three-page menu for an information website. I used an unordered list to make the menu, but I can't get it to change the opacity of the correct page container depending on which li is clicked.

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav_container">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav_services"><i></i>SERVICES</li>
        <li class="nav_home nav_active"><i></i>HOME</li>
        <li class="nav_contact"><i></i>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Update:** these are the div's I'm trying to alternately display.

```
<div id="services_container"></div>
<div id="home_container"></div>
<div id="home_container"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .nav_services:active:not(.nav_active) #services {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .nav_services:active:not(.nav_active) #home_container, #contact_container {
        opacity: 0;
    }


    .nav_home:active:not(.nav_active) #home_container {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .nav_home:active:not(.nav_active) #services_container, #contact_container {
        opacity: 0;
    }


    .nav_contact:active:not(.nav_active) #contact {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .nav_contact:active:not(.nav_active) #services, #home {
        opacity: 0;
    }
```

Honestly, I'm pretty sure it's the way I called the CSS, but I don't know how to properly write it.

Comment: Please add more detail about the desired result. By *page container*  do you mean LIs?

Comment: No I meant separate containers of the page. I'll update my code.

Answer (score 0):

Wound up just using jQuery to fulfill my problem. Simple function did the trick.

I would prefer CSS, but. This will do for now.

```
function page_handler() {
$('.nav_services').click(function () {
    if ($('.nav_services:not(.nav_active)')) {
        $('#services_container').css({
            opacity: 1
        });
        $('#home_container, #contact_container').css({
            opacity: 0
        });
    }
});
$('.nav_home').click(function () {
    if ($('.nav_home:not(.nav_active)')) {
        $('#home_container').css({
            opacity: 1
        });
        $('#services_container, #contact_container').css({
            opacity: 0
        });
    }
});
$('.nav_contact').click(function () {
    if ($('.nav_contact:not(.nav_active)')) {
        $('#contact_container').css({
            opacity: 1
        });
        $('#services_container, #home_container').css({
            opacity: 0
        });
    }
});
}
```